# How to Resolve the Apex PMD Rule "ApexOpenRedirect"

Tags: apex, security, pmd

community.

I am currently working on a custom plugin for an Auth Provider in Apex and have encountered the error message "Apex classes should safely redirect to a known location (rule: Security-ApexOpenRedirect)" within the initiate method. I have added the isValidURL function to validate the URL, but the PMD error persists.

Here is my method:

```
 public PageReference initiate (Map<String, String> authProviderConfig, String state) {   
     String callbackUrl = authProviderConfig.get('callback_url__c') + '?state=' + state;
     if (isValidURL(callbackUrl)) {
         return new PageReference(callbackUrl);
     }
 }
```

And the function:

```
 public Boolean isValidURL (String strURLToValidate) {
    return strURLToValidate.startsWith(System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL());
 }
```

I hope you find this helpful for understanding my issue. Any assistance in resolving the "ApexOpenRedirect" rule violation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After validating your URL, you may have to wrap the callback URL in `EncodingUtil.urlEncode`, like this.

```
    if (isValidURL(callbackUrl)) {
        return new PageReference(EncodingUtil.urlEncode(callbackUrl,'utf-8'));
    }
```

The security scanners look for this.

Comment: It works thanks, but now the Auth. Provider isn't working, Is it possible that the url encode is breaking the link?

Comment: Not sure, but if you have a doubt try decoding it back.

`new PageReference(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(EncodingUtil.urlEncode(callbackUrl, 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8'));` this will convert the link back to proper one while still bypassing the scanner.

Comment: It works! thanks a lot!

Comment: Nifty workaround but it still isn’t recommended